# Change order of radio button: display the checked above the drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, list, radio-button

I would like to have 3 radios visible and the others hidden in a drop-down. 
When a radio from the drop-down is selected, I would like it to move to the first place among the visible radio. The 3rd (or now the 4th) visible radio should move into the drop-down so that I always only have 3 radios visible.

I can't simply change the `label` because I use the radios' ID in the remaining script (cf the last line in the js script below):

I would like to use only vanilla `JS` (no Jquery...).

Here is my html:

```
<div id="sourcecontainer">
    <div> From
        <div>
            <input type="radio" id="fr" name="source" value="fr">
            <label for="fr">fr</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" id="en" name="source" value="en">
            <label for="en">en</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" id="auto" name="source" value="auto" checked>
            <label for="auto">auto</label>
        </div>
        <nav id="topNav">
            <a href="#" title="Others" id="othersLanguageSource">Others</a>
            <ul id="listothersLanguageSource" style="list-style: none; display:none;">
                <li><input type="radio" id="pr1" name="source" value="1">Preset 1</li>
                <li><input type="radio" id="pr2" name="source" value="2">Preset 2</li>
                <li><input type="radio" id="pr3" name="source" value="3">Preset 3</li>
                <li><input type="radio" id="pr4" name="source" value="4">Preset 4</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <input id="text" type="text" value="" autofocus />
</div>
```

Here is my js:

```
... 
var menuTopNav = document.getElementById('topNav');
menuTopNav.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    var listothersLanguageSource = document.getElementById("listothersLanguageSource")
    listothersLanguageSource.style.display = "block";
    listothersLanguageSource.style.display = "block";
}, false);
menuTopNav.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
    var listothersLanguageSource = document.getElementById("listothersLanguageSource")
    listothersLanguageSource.style.display = "none";
    listothersLanguageSource.style.display = "none";
}, false);

var sourceLang = document.querySelector('input[name="source"]:checked').value;
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```js
let langs = [
  { id: 'en', value: 'en', text: 'en' },
  { id: 'fr', value: 'fr', text: 'fr' },
  { id: 'auto', value: 'auto', text: 'auto', checked: true },
  { id: 'pr1', value: 'pr1', text: 'Preset 1' },
  { id: 'pr2', value: 'pr2', text: 'Preset 2' },
  { id: 'pr3', value: 'pr3', text: 'Preset 3' }
];

function render() {
  let mainLanguageSource = '';
  let othersLanguageSource = '';

  langs.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (index <= 2) {
      mainLanguageSource += '<div>'
        + '<input type="radio" id="' + langs[index].id + '" name="source" value="' + langs[index].value + '" ' + (langs[index].checked ? 'checked' : '') + '>'
        + '<label for="' + langs[index].id + '">' + langs[index].text + '</label>'
        + '</div>';
    } else {
      othersLanguageSource += '<li>'
        + '<input type="radio" id="' + langs[index].id + '" name="source" value="' + langs[index].value + '" ' + (langs[index].checked ? 'checked' : '') + '>'
        + '<label for="' + langs[index].id + '">' + langs[index].text + '</label>'
        + '</li>';
    }
  });


  document
    .getElementById('mainLanguageSource')
    .innerHTML = mainLanguageSource;

  document
    .getElementById('listothersLanguageSource')
    .innerHTML = othersLanguageSource;

  // add event listeners
  document.querySelectorAll('[name="source"]').forEach(function(input) {
    input.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
      let position;
      
      langs.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (item.id === event.target.value) {
          position = index;
          item.checked = true;
        } else {
          delete item.checked;
        }
      });
      
      langs.unshift(langs.splice(position, 1)[0]);
      
      render();
    });
  });
}

render();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sourcecontainer">
    <div> From
        <div id="mainLanguageSource">
            <!-- Filled from js -->
        </div
        <nav id="topNav">
            <a href="#" title="Others" id="othersLanguageSource">Others</a>
            <ul id="listothersLanguageSource" style="list-style:">
              <!-- Filled from js -->
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <input id="text" type="text" value="" autofocus />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```